# Delete all relations and connected nodes in Neo4j for a user

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We have selected neo4j as the DB for our web application. The user has a large number of relations and connected nodes. As of now there are about 20 relations for a user. One of the features is a newsfeed feature. If i want to delete a user completely, is the cypher query the best way to delete or is there any other alternative?

Since we are still planning to add new features, the relationships and nodes connected to the user also will increase. So if we use cypher query, the query has to be modified for every new relationship added. Please advise.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use Cypher to remove a user. Of course, there are alternative methods, depending on the language or framework you're using with your web application. If you like to have advise on that, please specifiy how you're using Neo4j in detail.

Note that you have to remove all relationships (outgoing and incoming) first in order to be able to remove the node.

Example:

```
START n = node(3)
MATCH n-[r]-()
DELETE n, r
```

This example was taken from the official manual: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-delete.html

Comment: Thanks Amorgner. Yeah I have seen this in the documentation. This is a direct relation to the node. In my case, the relations are complex, features like newsfeed are also there. I want to delete all the nodes which are associated with the user. For eg: The newsfeed feature, I want to delete the all the status updates and relations too before deleting the user node. It is a J2EE application. We are using spring-data neo4j. We also use cypher query to retrieve data.

Comment: Seems you need something like a 'cascading delete'. This has to be done on application level. I'm not sure how SDN handles this. In our framework, Structr (http://structr.org), you can define cascading delete rules as part of your bean model.

Comment: SDN doesn't handle cascading deletes, cypher is much better at describing a complex delete operation than any custom configuration language would be.

Comment: You can also filter types afterwards, even with parameters: `START n = node(3)
MATCH n-[r]-() WHERE type(r) in ['FOO','BAR']
DELETE n, r`

Answer (score 3):

As of Neo4j 2.3 there is another way to do this:

```
MATCH (n { name:'Andres' })
DETACH DELETE n
```

I found this example in the documentation at: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-delete.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to write a gremlin script that traverses your graph starting with your user and is putting in two collection the relationships and the nodes that you intend to delete. If you want to delete everything, perhaps you can implement your depth first traversal in Gremlin and delete while traversing.