# Delete multiple nodes with their relationships in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to delete some connected node together say **Photo**, with other connected nodes with relationship.
Case is like this:
**Album**-CONTAINS_PHOTO-**Photos**  (here could be multiple images)
**Photo**-taken_at-**Location**
**Photo**-HAS-**Comment**
**Comment**-ADDED_BY-**User**

**I want to delete from Photo to Comment node.** (Since Album and user is parent node hence I dont need to delete them unless n until required)
On neo4j webadmin console I am firing this query:

```
start pht=node:__types__(className="org.sg.domain.Photo"),
cmt=node:__types__(className="org.sg.domain.Comments") 
MATCH pht-[r:HAS]-x,pht-[t:taken_at]-x, cmt-[s]-y 
WHERE pht.photoId="MhQ2W1GrJ" AND 
pht.albumName="FirstAlbum" AND
pht.userName="abc" delete r,s,t,pht,cmt;
```

(where 'x' and 'y' is general placeholders.)

I am getting this output:

```
Invalid query
Node[7] has been deleted in this tx
```

(where `Node[7]` is denoted for Photo object. Although it shows Node[7] deleted but thats not correct).
I changed my criteria to `MATCH` node relationship as
`MATCH pht-[r]-x`,`MATCH pht-[r?:HAS | :taken_at]-x`,
`MATCH pht-[r:HAS]-x, pht-[s:taken_at]-x`, but no result.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283743/delete-all-relations-and-connected-nodes-in-neo4j-for-a-user) and [official link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-delete.html#delete-delete-a-node-and-connected-relationships), but I guess, I am little away from something.. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate query and modifing parts of a cypher query for [updating the graph](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-updating.html). `WITH` is used as separation token:

```
START pht=node:__types__(className="org.sg.domain.Photo"),
cmt=node:__types__(className="org.sg.domain.Comments") 
MATCH pht-[r:HAS]-x,pht-[t:taken_at]-x, cmt-[s]-y 
WHERE pht.photoId="MhQ2W1GrJ" AND 
pht.albumName="FirstAlbum" AND
pht.userName="abc" 

WITH r,s,t,pht,cmt
delete r,s,t,pht,cmt;
```

Comment: Thanks thomas, for updating my knowledge. I am trying little bit more in this to make query more specific. May I edit your answer a little bit so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Your change was rejected before I even saw it. It was considered too extensive and not fitting the question.

Comment: I just added `MATCH photo-[r?:HAS]->x-[s?:ADDED_BY]-y,photo-[t:taken_at]-z,
photo<-[c:CONTAINS_PHOTO]-alb` and delete relationship first followed by node variable. It worked.